# Weird Spacing of Square Brackets and added .00s in Table with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx, alignment

I use the `siunitx` package to align numbers in a table column at their "dot". This used to work fine. When I re-compile an old TeX file, square brackets around the numbers are suddenly  weirdly spaced and numbers in the column titles (I use numbers to label the columns) are transformed from (1) to (1.00).

Below I show the current result of `siunitx` with the weird spacing of brackets and the artificially added .00s. I also show a table which does not use `siunitx` and looks normal (but does not align numbers in a column at their dot).

**Question**: Was there an update to `siunitx` that changed how it works? How can avoid the odd spacing of square brackets and the adding of zeros in the column titles while aligning numbers at their dot?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker = \text{e}, 
         exponent-product={}, 
         retain-explicit-plus, 
         input-open-uncertainty  = , 
         input-close-uncertainty = , 
         table-align-text-pre    = false,
         table-align-text-post = false, 
         round-mode=places, 
         round-precision=2, 
         table-space-text-pre = (, table-space-text-post   = )}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S} 
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (3)--(1) & & (4) & (5) & (6) & (6)--(4) \\ \midrule
Row 1 & 0.96  & 0.60  & 0.45  & -0.50 &       & 0.69  & 0.84  & 0.64  & -0.05 \\ \midrule
Row 2 & [3.93] & [2.75] & [1.93] & [-3.64] &       & [3.47] & [4.68] & [3.10] & [-0.59]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (3)--(1) & & (4) & (5) & (6) & (6)--(4) \\ \midrule
Row 1 & 0.96  & 0.60  & 0.45  & -0.50 &       & 0.69  & 0.84  & 0.64  & -0.05 \\ \midrule
Row 2 & [3.93] & [2.75] & [1.93] & [-3.64] &       & [3.47] & [4.68] & [3.10] & [-0.59]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are some changes here to allow `table-format` to be extended, and that means that `table-space-text-pre = (, table-space-text-post = )` is now emulation (and gets overwritten in some places).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes there have been many recent changes to `siunitx`.  In this case, to avoid the decimalization of the top row, enclose the cell contents in braces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker = \text{e}, 
         exponent-product={}, 
         retain-explicit-plus, 
         input-open-uncertainty  = , 
         input-close-uncertainty = , 
         table-align-text-pre    = false,
         table-align-text-post = false, 
         round-mode=places, 
         round-precision=2, 
         table-space-text-pre = (, table-space-text-post   = )}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S @{} S} 
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(3)--(1)} & & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(6)--(4)} \\ \midrule
Row 1 & 0.96  & 0.60  & 0.45  & -0.50 &       & 0.69  & 0.84  & 0.64  & -0.05 \\ \midrule
Row 2 & [3.93] & [2.75] & [1.93] & [-3.64] &       & [3.47] & [4.68] & [3.10] & [-0.59]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (3)--(1) & & (4) & (5) & (6) & (6)--(4) \\ \midrule
Row 1 & 0.96  & 0.60  & 0.45  & -0.50 &       & 0.69  & 0.84  & 0.64  & -0.05 \\ \midrule
Row 2 & [3.93] & [2.75] & [1.93] & [-3.64] &       & [3.47] & [4.68] & [3.10] & [-0.59]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To specify the format of the brackets, use `table-format` option to `S`.  Of course, if there are multiple rows in play, you only get one `S[table-format...]` per column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker = \text{e}, 
         exponent-product={}, 
         retain-explicit-plus, 
         input-open-uncertainty  = , 
         input-close-uncertainty = , 
         table-align-text-pre    = false,
         table-align-text-post = false, 
         round-mode=places, 
         round-precision=2, 
         table-space-text-pre = (, table-space-text-post   = )}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=2.2] @{} S[table-format=2.2] @{} 
  S[table-format=2.2] @{} S[table-format=3.2] @{} S[table-format=2.2] @{} 
  S[table-format=2.2] @{} S[table-format=2.2] @{} S[table-format=2.2] @{} 
  S[table-format=3.2]} 
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(3)--(1)} & & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(6)--(4)} \\ \midrule
Row 1 & 0.96  & 0.60  & 0.45  & -0.50 &       & 0.69  & 0.84  & 0.64  & -0.05 \\ \midrule
Row 2 & [3.93] & [2.75] & [1.93] & [-3.64] &       & [3.47] & [4.68] & [3.10] & [-0.59]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (3)--(1) & & (4) & (5) & (6) & (6)--(4) \\ \midrule
Row 1 & 0.96  & 0.60  & 0.45  & -0.50 &       & 0.69  & 0.84  & 0.64  & -0.05 \\ \midrule
Row 2 & [3.93] & [2.75] & [1.93] & [-3.64] &       & [3.47] & [4.68] & [3.10] & [-0.59]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing and worked, +1! The only remaining question is the spacing of the square brackets. There seems to be a gap in columns (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) and (6), because these numbers are not negative? How can the square brackets be displayed directly enclosing the numbers?

Comment: @Alex Please see my edit...you can use `table-format` option to `S`.

Answer (score 2):

If I compile your (first) table with TeX Live 2020 (and so `siunitx` version 2), I get

[image]

which is not really a good output. It's a bit annoying, but in order to get precise alignments you need to set the format for each column and the headers should be braced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  output-exponent-marker = \text{e}, 
  exponent-product={}, 
  retain-explicit-plus, 
  input-open-uncertainty  = , 
  input-close-uncertainty = , 
  table-align-text-pre    = false,
  table-align-text-post = false, 
  round-mode=places, 
  round-precision=2, 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
% this is for this specific table
\sisetup{
  table-space-text-pre = (,
  table-space-text-post   = ),
}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(3)--(1)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(6)--(4)} \\
\midrule
Row 1 &  0.96  &  0.60  &  0.45  &  -0.50  &  0.69  &  0.84  &  0.64  &  -0.05 \\
\midrule
Row 2 & [3.93] & [2.75] & [1.93] & [-3.64] & [3.47] & [4.68] & [3.10] & [-0.59] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Compiling the above with `siunitx` version 2 I get

[image]

If I try with `siunitx` version 3, the result is not as good, because something has indeed changed. Here's the new code: the brackets should be specified in the `table-format`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  output-exponent-marker = \text{e}, 
  exponent-product={}, 
  retain-explicit-plus, 
  input-open-uncertainty  = , 
  input-close-uncertainty = , 
  table-align-text-pre    = false,
  table-align-text-post = false, 
  round-mode=places, 
  round-precision=2, 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format={[1.2]}]
  S[table-format={[1.2]}]
  S[table-format={[1.2]}]
  S[table-format={[-1.2]}]
  S[table-format={[1.2]}]
  S[table-format={[1.2]}]
  S[table-format={[1.2]}]
  S[table-format={[-1.2]}]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(3)--(1)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(6)--(4)} \\
\midrule
Row 1 &  0.96  &  0.60  &  0.45  &  -0.50  &  0.69  &  0.84  &  0.64  &  -0.05 \\
Row 2 & [3.93] & [2.75] & [1.93] & [-3.64] & [3.47] & [4.68] & [3.10] & [-0.59] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also omitted one `\midrule` that serves no purpose.

[image]

Comment: You could put `,table-space-text-pre = (, table-space-text-post = )` after each of the `table-format` entries in your v2 demo and it would also work for v3

Answer (score 1):

To long for the comment. For this particular table and use `siunitx` version 3.0.22 the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format={[}1.2{]}}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
                    SSS 
                    S[table-format={[}-1.2{]}] 
                    SSS 
                    S[table-format={[}-1.2{]}] @{}}
    \toprule
      & {(1)}   & {(2)}  & {(3)} & {(3)--(1)} & {(4)}  & {(5)}  & {(6)}  & {(6)--(4)}\\
    \midrule
Row 1 &  0.96  &  0.60  &  0.45  &  -0.50     &  0.69  &  0.84  &  0.64  &  -0.05    \\
Row 2 & [3.93] & [2.75] & [1.93] & [-3.64]    & [3.47] & [4.68] & [3.10] & [-0.59]   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]